# Accessing the default argument values in Python

Tags: python

How can I programmatically access the default argument values of a method in Python? For example, in the following

```
def test(arg1='Foo'):
    pass
```

how can I access the string `'Foo'` inside `test`?

Comment: Can you provide an example demonstrating why you might want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean NOT just typing `arg1`?

Comment: If you don't provide `arg1` when calling `test`, then `arg1` will default to `'Foo'`

Comment: @orangeoctopus: Well `arg1` can be overwritten, right?

Comment: "Well arg1 can be overwritten, right?"?  What do you mean by that.  You can't change the default.  But you can provide a argument value.  What do you mean "overwritten"?

Comment: @S.Lott: I mean you can call `test(arg1='Bar')` and have `arg1`'s default value overwritten. I don't understand your question.

Comment: That's not "overwriting" anything.  That's simply providing an argument value to a parameter with a default value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are stored in `test.func_defaults` (python 2) and in `test.__defaults__` (python 3).

As @Friedrich reminds me, Python 3 has "keyword only" arguments, and for those the defaults are stored in `function.__kwdefaults__`

Comment: See also [`__kwdefaults__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17533929).

Answer (score 5):

Consider:

```
def test(arg1='Foo'):
    pass

In [48]: test.func_defaults
Out[48]: ('Foo',)
```

`.func_defaults` gives you the default values, as a sequence, in order that the arguments appear in your code.

Apparently, `func_defaults` may have been removed in python 3.

Comment: I think `func_defaults` only works on Python 2.x. `__defaults__` seems to work on Python 2.7 and 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

Ricardo Cárdenes is on the right track. Actually getting to the function `test` *inside* `test` is going to be a lot more tricky. The `inspect` module will get you further, but it is going to be ugly: [Python code to get current function into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492559/python-code-to-get-current-function-into-a-variable)

As it turns out, you can refer to `test` inside the function:

```
def test(arg1='foo'):
    print test.__defaults__[0]
```

Will print out `foo`. But refering to `test` will only work, as long as `test` is actually defined:

```
>>> test()
foo
>>> other = test
>>> other()
foo
>>> del test
>>> other()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in test
NameError: global name 'test' is not defined
```

So, if you intend on passing this function around, you might really have to go the `inspect` route :(

Comment: I was under that impression as well, turns out that `test` is in `test`'s local scope as pointed out in Ricardo's comment on my answer.

Comment: If we do `def test2(): print locals(), '\n\n', globals()`, we see that `test2` is in globals, and there is nothing in locals.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very elegant (at all), but it does what you want:

```
def test(arg1='Foo'):
    print(test.__defaults__)

test(arg1='Bar')
```

Works with Python 3.x too.

Comment: Why `globals()`? `test` is local in its own scope, no need for that.

Comment: @RicardoCárdenes, you're right. I did not know that, thank you. Fixing it now.