# What is the use of __kwdefaults__ which is a function object attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Function object has attributes `__defaults__` and `__kwdefaults__`. I see that if a function has some default arguments then they are put as a tuple to `__defaults__` but `__kwdefaults__` is `None`. When is used attribute `__kwdefaults__`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3, *args, kwarg1="FOO", kwarg2="BAR", kwarg3="BAZ"):
    pass

print(foo.__kwdefaults__)
```

Output (Python 3):

```
{'kwarg1': 'FOO', 'kwarg2': 'BAR', 'kwarg3': 'BAZ'}
```

Since the `*args` would swallow all non-keyword arguments, the arguments after it have to be passed with keywords. See [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

Answer (score 10):

It is used for [keyword-only arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
>>> def a(a, *, b=2): pass
...
>>> a.__kwdefaults__
{'b': 2}

>>> def a(*args, a=1): pass
...
>>> a.__kwdefaults__
{'a': 1}
```