# How can a function refer stably to itself?

Tags: python, introspection

[The code in the original version was badly messed up.  Even after I fixed the code, several highly confusing typos remained in the post.  I believe I finally fixed all of them too.  Profuse apologies.]

The two calls to `alias` below produce different outputs, because the object associated with the variable `my_own_id` changes between the two calls:

```
>>> def my_own_id():
...     me = my_own_id
...     return id(me)
... 
>>> alias = my_own_id
>>> alias()
4301701560
>>> my_own_id = None
>>> alias()
4296513024
```

What can I assign to `me` in the definition of `my_own_id` so that its output remains invariant wrt subsequent re-definitions of the `my_own_id` variable?  (IOW, so that the internal `me` variable always refers to the same function object?)

(I can get the current frame (with `inspect.currentframe()`), but it contains only a reference to the current code object, not to the current function.)

P.S. The motivation for this question is only to know Python better.

Comment: Where is `spam` defined?

Comment: The example is somewhat confusing - are `ham` and `spam` references to `my_own_id()`?

Comment: Nice find :-)  [you should edit the question renaming my_own_id to spam] I have no idea why this happens though. If you assign again, it remains stable: `foo = ham; ham(); del ham; foo()` (which I suppose is the answer to your questions, although without any insight :-)

Comment: This is interesting: `>>> id(my_own_id)
45375408
>>> alias = my_own_id
>>> id(alias)
45375408
>>> my_own_id = None
>>> id(my_own_id)
505354444
>>> id(alias)
45375408
>>> alias()
505354444`

Comment: @MartijnPieters: my code was messed up; I have fixed it now.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @voithos: see my comment to MartijnPieters.  Apologies to you too, and everyone else, for the badly mangled original post.

Comment: The question is very interesting. How to get the function object from within the function itself ?

Comment: Note that the return value from the final call to `alias()` is the id of `None` -- i.e., "what's the ID of the object that the name 'my_own_id' is bound to"?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that referring to `my_own_id` will look for `'my_own_id'` in the global namespace dictionary, so it will always be the name used on function definition. Since that name can be assigned to different values, the value retrieved can also change. If you make `me` a default argument, you can assign it to the function itself at function definition to keep a reference to the actual function.

You could use this decorator which implicitly passes the original function itself as the first argument.

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def save_id(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper


>>> @save_id
def my_own_id(me): # me is passed implicitly by save_id
    return id(me)

>>> alias = my_own_id
>>> alias()
40775152
>>> my_own_id = 'foo'
>>> alias()
40775152
```

Comment: Did you actually try that? I get a NameError in python 2.6.1; at the point where the arguments are parsed, the name `my_own_id` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @RussellBorogove just tried it on 2.6.5 and 2.7 and it seems to work. http://ideone.com/EtXTY & http://ideone.com/bbBSC

Comment: Ah, I left out the `my_own_id = None` line. You're getting the id of `None`, not the id of the function. (I'm talking about your first stanza here, not the decorator version.)

Comment: @RussellBorogove Oh I'll just get rid of that solution. I could have actually got the id of an `object()` I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, if you rely only on the function name, if that name is overitten in the global variable space (in the module the function was defined), a reference using the name of the function itslef will fail

The easier, more maintanable way is to write a decorator for that, that would provide a `nonlocal`variable containing a reference to the function itself.

```
from functools import wraps

def know_thyself(func):
   @wraps(func):
   def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        my_own_id = func
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
   return new_func
```

And can be used as:

```
>>> @know_thyself
... def my_own_id():
...     me = my_own_id
...     return id(me)
...
```

There is another possible approach, far from being this clean, using frame introspection
and rebuilding a new function re-using the same object code. I had used this on this post
about a self-referential lambda expression in Python:
http://metapython.blogspot.com.br/2010/11/recursive-lambda-functions.html

Comment: Probably want to change the names, since as currently written this doesn't quite work: you define the `own_id` variable but then don't use it.

Comment: Er, I don't think this works either... nonlocal scope only works on an enclosing scope, not through callers.  since the definition of `my_own_id` is not inside of either `know_thyself` nor `new_func`; none of the names are visible (short of some frame inspecting shenanegans)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't mind calling a function (to get the desired function into the global scope), you can wrap the function to protect its definition:

```
>>> def be_known():
...     global my_own_id
...     def _my_own_id():
...         return id(_my_own_id)
...     my_own_id = _my_own_id
... 
>>> be_known()
>>> my_own_id()
140685505972568
>>> alias, my_own_id = my_own_id, None
>>> alias()
140685505972568
```

Note that the protected function must call itself with the nonlocal name, not the global name.

Answer (score 1):

The decorator approach is probably the best one. Here are some more for fun:

1. Hijack one of the function arguments to provide a static variable.

   ```
   def fn(fnid=None):
       print "My id:", fnid
   fn.func_defaults = (id(fn),)
   ```
2. There are a few ways to get the current function here: [Python code to get current function into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492559/python-code-to-get-current-function-into-a-variable); most of these involve searching for currentframe.f_code in a variety of places. These work without any modification to the original function.

Answer (score 1):

```
import inspect
def _this_fn():
    try:
        frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
        code = frame.f_code
        return frame.f_globals[code.co_name]
    finally:
        del code
        del frame

def myfunc(*parms):
    print _this_fn()

>>> myfunc(1)
<function myfunc at 0x036265F0>
>>> myfunc
<function myfunc at 0x036265F0>
```

Comment: Interesting, but this won't work, as you'll see if you replace the line `me = my_own_id` with `me = _this_fn()` in the test case I posted.  Out of curiosity, why bother with `del code` and `del frame` (and with them the need for the `try...finally` structure) in `_this_fn`?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to scope

```
>>> def foo():
...     x = foo
...     print x
... 
>>> foo()
<function foo at 0x10836e938>
>>> alias = foo
>>> alias()
<function foo at 0x10836e938>
>>> foo = None
>>> alias()
None
>>> foo = []
>>> alias()
[]
>>> del foo
>>> alias()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in foo
NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: I think the question is not _why_, but rather how to circumvent.

Comment: @Luke: yeah, I know. I am curious as well. I leave the answer as is for future reference though.

Answer (score 0):

[Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908652/5987) had an idea but didn't appear to develop it: use a mutable default parameter to hold the value in the function object. Default parameter values are evaluated only once, when the function is defined, and retain their previous value after that.

```
>>> def my_own_id(me=[None]):
    if not me[0]:
        me[0] = my_own_id
    return id(me[0])

>>> alias = my_own_id
>>> alias()
40330928
>>> my_own_id = None
>>> alias()
40330928
```

This requires care on your part to never call the function with a parameter.

Comment: This of course only works if the function is called before reassigning the name.

Comment: @Dougal you can put the first call right after the definition, just to make sure.

Comment: Well, yes, but if it's an expensive function call you don't necessarily want to do that. Just pointing out that this isn't foolproof.