# how to get the pointer to the current function in python?

Tags: python, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python code to get current function into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492559/python-code-to-get-current-function-into-a-variable)

is there a convenient way to get to pointer of current function?

for example:

```
current_func_ref = None
def func():
    current_func_ref = ___ #something need to fill
    do something..
```

Comment: You want a reference to the current function being called on the stack?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the end? This is a very strange pattern for Python.

Comment: note: `current_func_ref` inside the function creates a *local* name. It has no effect on `current_func_ref` at the outer level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is a bit cheeky, not very generic like you might want, but here it is anyway:

```
current_func_ref = None
def func():
    global current_func_ref
    current_func_ref = func
```

Comment: when you change the functions name ,you also need to change the code.

Comment: @user1544915 Yep, hence me describing it as cheeky and not generic. But like the other commentors have said, even wanting to do this in the first place is odd. What problem are you actually trying to solve?