# Getting the name of the @property being accessed, set or deleted in Python

Tags: python, properties

Is it possible in Python to get the name of property currently being accessed, modified for deleted inside the function?  For example, I've got this code with some pseudo-code inside:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        prop = get_current_property() #prop is set to 'x'
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        prop = get_current_property() #prop is set to 'x'
        return self._x


    @property
    def y(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        prop = get_current_property() #prop is set to 'y'
        return self._x
```

So the pseudo-code here is the `get_current_property()`, which should work inside of the getter, setter and deleter methods for each property.  Any way to do this?

Comment: Related: [Python code to get current function into a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4492559)

Comment: No, you cannot, not really. The function object has no reference to itself, let alone the property object. Various tricks with introspection have been proposed, but the bottom line is: just put the name in a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is no way to make it easy and sexy. Only dirty-inspecty magic, my friend.

```
import inspect
class A(object):
    @property
    def b(self):
        print inspect.stack()[0][3]

A().b
```

will give you result you want, but you should do it **only** if there is no way you can deal with your things.

Btw, you can try to make a decorator, which will take a function, take its `__name__` and send it as argument.

Here is implementation of idea:

```
def named_property(func):
    return property(lambda *a, **kwa: func(*a, fname=func.__name__, **kwa))

class A(object):
    @named_property
    def b(self, fname):
        print fname
A().b  # will print 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Martijn Pieters said, there is no straightforward way for the method to get a reference to itself.

I'm trying to understand **why** the property definition (written by you) wouldn't already know its own name. I'm guessing that you want to do this so that you can create a bunch of properties programmatically without a separate explicit defitinition for each one.

Try something like this to build a new class dynamically while creating some of its properties from a list:

```
def make_getter_setter(name):
    # this function uses an implicit closure to "freeze" the local value of name
    # within the scope of the getter/setter functions
    def getter(self):
        return name
    def setter(self):
        pass # your original code doesn't make clear that the setter should actually do anything

    return getter, setter    

class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # dictionary to store the values of the properties
        # this doesn't do anything now, but I presume you'll want to allow
        # setting the properties later, and you'll need somewhere to store
        # their values
        self._properties = {}

for name in ('spam', 'eggs', 'ham'):
    getter, setter = make_getter_setter(name)
    setattr(C, name, property(getter, setter, doc="I'm the '%s' property" % name))

foo = C()
print foo.eggs, foo.ham    # shows their values
help(foo)                  # shows their doc strings
```