# How to access a caller method's __class__ attribute from a callee function in Python?

Tags: python, code-inspection, class-attributes

Here `__class__` should not be confused with `self.__class__` which I am already able to access with the `inspect` module:

```
import inspect


class A:

    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)  # I want to move this statement inside f
        f()


class B(A):
    pass


def f():
    prev_frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    self = prev_frame.f_locals["self"]
    print(self.__class__.__name__)


B()  # prints A B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [implicit `__class__` reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) is created at compile-time only if you actually reference it within the method (or use `super`). For example this code:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        print('bar', locals())

    def baz(self):
        print('baz', locals())

        if False:
            __class__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()

    foo.bar()
    foo.baz()
```

Produces this output:

```
bar {'self': <__main__.Foo object at 0x10f45f978>}
baz {'self': <__main__.Foo object at 0x10f45f978>, '__class__': <class '__main__.Foo'>}
```

To find the calling function's class (in most cases) you could chain together a few CPython-specific `inspect` incantations:

1. Find the calling function: [How to get current function into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492559/how-to-get-current-function-into-a-variable)
2. Find that function's class: [Get defining class of unbound method object in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589311/get-defining-class-of-unbound-method-object-in-python-3)

I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Since the OP only needs the name of the class, they could just use `inspect` to get the calling function and extract the class name from that function's `__qualname__`. No real need to get the class object.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: The question title referred to using the `__class__` reference so I assumed `__class__.__name__` is just an example. But yes, if all you need is the name of the parent class then you could just use the approach from the first linked question and `__qualname__`.

Comment: I was actually trying to reimplement the `super` class in Python to understand its behavior, so I need the class object @Aran-Fey. And I was at the syntactic sugar part `super() == super(__class__, self)`. Why did they choose to create the `__class__` implicit closure reference only "if any methods in a class body refer to either `__class__` or `super`" instead of always? My `super` class reimplementation is not called `super` so `__class__` is not created and I am left with @Blender CPython hack (thank you by the way).

Comment: @Maggyero: I'm not very familiar with CPython internals or its history so I'm not 100% sure. It's been this way since the first commit that introduced it.