# How can I get the function object inside a lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Sorry if this is very lame, but I'm pretty new to Python.

As in Python everything is an object, I assume in every object the object itself can be get somehow. In object methods the `self` variable contains it. From the object reference the class object can be get (like `type(self)`). But how this could be got inside a lambda?

I could figure out for a normal function:

```
import inspect

def named_func():
    func_name = inspect.stack()[0].function
    func_obj = inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_locals[func_name]
    print(func_name, func_obj, func_obj.xxx)

named_func.xxx = 15
named_func()
```

The output looks like this:

```
named_func <function named_func at 0x7f56e368c2f0> 15
```

Unfortunately in a lambda the `inspect.stack()[0].function` gives `<lambda>` inside the lambda.

Is there a way to get the function object inside a lambda?
Is there a way to get function object directly (not using the name of the function)?
I imagined `__self__`, but it does not work.

**UPDATE**

I tried something like this in lambda:

```
lambda_func = lambda : inspect.stack()[0]
lambda_func.xxx = 2
print(lambda_func())
```

This prints:

```
FrameInfo(frame=<frame at 0x7f3eee8a6378, file './test_obj.py', line 74, code <lambda>>, filename='./test_obj.py', lineno=74, function='<lambda>', code_context=['lambda_func = lambda : inspect.stack()[0]\n'], index=0)
```

But for example is there a way to get the lambda object field `xxx` in this case? For this the lambda object should be got somehow.

Comment: Can you give a [mre] of your lambda?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get current function into a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492559/how-to-get-current-function-into-a-variable)

Comment: Are you doing this just for learning, or do you have a practical use case?

Comment: @flakes The cited question is about how to get the object inside a normal function. This is my example code. But I would like to go a step forward to do similar inside a lambda function.

Comment: @0x5453 Does it matter? :) Actually, I would like to get the function's property without referring to the name of the function. So, if I rename the function, I do not have consider change inside the function.

Comment: The PEP for this was [specifically rejected](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3130/). Just use a named function, and use the name.

Comment: `self` is just a parameter whose argument is set by the `method` instance that wraps the function used to define it.  A lambda expression *already* defines a "normal function"; there is no fundamental difference between objects defined by `def` statements and objects defined by lambda expressions.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica Thx for the PEP! It is sad that this was refused. Actually (IMHO) it should be extended by __lambda__ or __function__ would do the job. For me it is strange that this was not implemented in the original version of the language...

Comment: @chepner You are absolutely right about this! Used as to show that there are some possibilities, but there are a lot of missing ones. But as the rejected PEP shows, it was not just my idea how this should work to be more complete.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note, this is not an efficient/pragmatic solution to the problem. This is not a recommendation about how to write actual software.. it simply presents how access to the lambda reference from the lambda can be achieved without assigning it to a variable name. This is a very hacky answer.

This will only work completely correctly if you follow the advice from the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506081/3280538)

In short, given the `stack` you can find the `code` object, and then using the `gc` module you can find the reference to your lambda.

Example with [@Tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s factorial lambda!

```
import gc
import inspect


def current_lambda():
    lambda_code = inspect.stack()[1].frame.f_code
    candidates = [
        referrer
        for referrer in gc.get_referrers(lambda_code)
        if inspect.isfunction(referrer)
        and referrer.__code__ is lambda_code
    ]
    if len(candidates) != 1:
        raise ValueError(
            "Multiple candidates found! Cannot determine correct function!"
        )
    return candidates[0]


print((lambda n: 1 if n < 2 else n * current_lambda()(n - 1))(5))
```

Outputs

```
120
```

Revisiting your example:

```
lambda_func = lambda: current_lambda().xxx
lambda_func.xxx = 10
print(lambda_func())
```

Outputs:

```
10
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks! I used this `lfunc = lambda : gc.get_referrers(inspect.stack()[0].frame.f_code)[0]` and now `print(lfunc)` and `print(lfunc())` gives the same result: `<function <lambda> at 0x7f8305a02840>`! Super! And this also works for normal functions as well!

Comment: This is **absurdly** slow, since it requires a search through literally every single GC-tracked object in the entire program. That means the issue won't be obvious in a toy example program, but once you've got more objects, this rapidly becomes unusable, even if those objects have nothing to do with the lambda you're looking for.

Comment: It also fails if multiple functions are using the same code object, which happens consistently in some cases with closures, but can also happen inconsistently in multi-threaded programs, leading to hard-to-reproduce bugs.

Comment: @flakes I applied this to a class-object and I got back a function-object for my surprise! It is like: `class X(): print(gc.get_referrers(inspect.stack()[0].frame.f_code)[0])`. This gives <`function X at 0x7fb7f1c94048>`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica You are right! There are issues with this approach. But my question was about if this is possible and it is! :) IMHO this is a (not the biggest) problem of Python that it states that everything is an object, but sometimes it is rather difficult to get the "self" pointer of a lambda or of a class inside the class body. Maybe some kind of automatism (like `__self__`) could be implemented to support this. But maybe I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

We can now use a new python syntax to make it shorter and easier to read, without the need to define a new function for this purpose.

You can find two examples below:

Fibonacci:

```py
(f:=lambda x: 1 if x <= 1 else f(x - 1) + f(x - 2))(5)
```

Factorial:

```py
(f:=lambda x: 1 if x == 0 else x*f(x - 1))(5)
```

We use `:=` to name the lambda: use the name directly in the lambda itself and call it right away as an anonymous function.

So in your particular use-case it would give something like that:

```py
print((f:=lambda: f.__hash__())())  # prints the hash for example
```

You can do whatever you want with that `f` variable now (inside the lambda).

But in fact, if you don't mind multi-lines for your code, you could also just use the name directly and do something like that:

```py
f = lambda : f.xxx
f.xxx = 2
print(f())
```

(see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572 for more information about this `:=` operator)

Comment: This is not a duplicate answer! I added a lot more details and explained the specific use case of the user. I just use two examples coming from another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70731695/14580601