# String representation of nested function with stackframe/inspection

Tags: python, trace

I am working on generating a call graph for a large codebase, and I would like to generate a nice string representation for nested functions/closures - e.g. something like `Test.a.b` for this function:

```py
class Test:
    def a(self):
        def b():
            pass
```

Currently I have the following:

```py
import inspect


def trace(frame):

    code = frame.f_code

    module = inspect.getmodule(code)
    module_name = module.__name__ if module else None

    try:
        class_name = frame.f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__
    except (KeyError, AttributeError):
        class_name = None

    func_name = code.co_name

    print(module_name, class_name, func_name)
```

If I call this from my test class:

```py
class Test:
    def a(self):
        trace(inspect.currentframe())

        def b():
            trace(inspect.currentframe())

        b()


def main():
    test = Test()
    test.a()
```

Then I get the following output:

```
__main__ Test a  
__main__ None b
```

Is there a way to detect that `b` is defined within `Test.a`?

I know that it's possible to achieve this with the string representation of the function itself, e.g. `<function Test.a.<locals>.b at 0x105976fc0>` obtained [via this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506081/1129194), but I am wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: scope in python: [scope explained](https://youtu.be/tACcA5s3SM4)

Comment: even if one was going to nest a function inside another function (which is a bad structural idea in general), the purpose of that would be to hide that function from the rest of the code. Otherwise one would just write the function as it exists. . . . make code simple and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that without any extra imports, using `code` objects.

Here a basic example:

```
def cls_struct(cls):
    
    # auxiliary recursive function
    def __cls_struct(codes):
        res = []
        for c in codes:
            if c is None or isinstance(c, str):
                # if a nested class is met (as string identifier)
                pass
            elif c.co_consts[1:]:
                res.append(c.co_qualname)            
                res.extend(__cls_struct(c.co_consts[1:]))
            else:
                res.append(c.co_qualname)
    
         return res


    # collect the code objects of the specified class
    codes = []
    for m_name in dir(cls):
        # skep dunder methods
        if not (m_name.startswith('__') and m_name.endswith('__')):
            m = getattr(cls, m_name)
            # method only, no attr
            if callable(m):
                codes.append(m.__code__)

    # recursive call
    return __cls_struct(codes)
```

The test cases

```
# nested function declaration
class Test:
    def a(self):
        def b():
            def c():
                pass

print(cls_struct(Test))
['Test.a', 'Test.a.<locals>.b', 'Test.a.<locals>.b.<locals>.c']


# inheritance with nested class declaration
class Test2(Test):
    def b(self):
        class __Test: #    nested class are detected
            def w(self):
                def x(): pass
    def c():
        lambda: None
    
    def d():
        return lambda: None # decorator are detected


print(cls_struct(Test2))
['Test.a', 'Test.a.<locals>.b', 'Test.a.<locals>.b.<locals>.c', 'Test.a.<locals>.b.<locals>.c.<locals>.d', 'Test.a.<locals>.<lambda>', 'Test.a.<locals>.<lambda>.<locals>.<lambda>', 'Test2.b', 'Test2.b.<locals>.__Test', 'Test2.b.<locals>.__Test.w', 'Test2.b.<locals>.__Test.w.<locals>.x', 'Test2.c', 'Test2.c.<locals>.<lambda>', 'Test2.d', 'Test2.d.<locals>.<lambda>']
```

---

To have a more compact output it should be

- changed `co_qualname` attribute of the code object with `co_name`, so for example `cls_struct(Test)` will return `['a', 'b', 'c']`
- removed the `<locals>` parts from the `co_qualname` with `c.co_qualname.replace('<locals>.', '')`, so `cls_struct(Test)` will be a bit more descriptive `['Test.a', 'Test.a.b', 'Test.a.b.c']`
- removed or substitute the `<lambda>` as in previous case `c.co_qualname.replace('<lambda>.', '?')`

---

It can be used also in *syntactic sugar* form

```
@cls_struct
class Test2(Test):
    [...]

print(Test2)
```